# Add existing key as value to a new key in a java property file

Tags: java, json, properties-file

I am using a properties file in my java project for storing the path of various resources.
Ex :- Here is my properties file :-

```
MACHINE_NAME = "//pranay"
Json_path1 = MACHINE_NAME//Json//j1.txt
Json_path2 = MACHINE_NAME//Json//j2.txt
```

The value of key MACHINE_NAME is not getting replaced with its value i.e pranay in another keys such as Json_path1 and Json_path2. Therefore i am unable to get the correct path.
How to give the key MACHINE_NAME so that its value gets replaced in the other key values.

Comment: Why have you doubled the forward-slashes, by the way?

Comment: I have written it in such a manner as it is written for windows

Comment: That doesn't mean you need to use doubled forward-slashes. You would need to double *backslashes*, but not forward slashes (within the path).

Comment: Will it be compatible for linux and other os too ??

Comment: A single forward-slash is compatible everywhere, as far as I'm aware. Backslashes are Windows-specific.

Comment: single forward-slash is not working for windows

Comment: "is not working" doesn't say anything about what you're doing with it, or in what way it's not working - I suggest you ask a separate question about that, as it's not *really* what this question is about... it was just a casual remark.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this automatically - it's simply not a feature of Java property files. You'll need to write code to do this wherever you plan to load/use the properties file.

You should think about:

- whether you want to make this more explicit, e.g. using `${MACHINE_NAME}` instead of just `MACHINE_NAME`
- whether you have a fixed list of replacements you want to support, or whether you want to pick up *anything* that looks like it's a replacement (much easier if you have a syntax such as `${...}` of course)
- whether replacements can be recursive, e.g. `MACHINE_NAME = ${USER_NAME}-laptop` - and how to handle cycles if so

Comment: Is there any concatenation character like '+' or '&' ??

Comment: @PranayWankhede: No, properties files are *just* key-value maps. There's no extra processing between entries.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Properties mechanism cannot handle this, but there are extensions. Try to look at [eproperties](https://code.google.com/p/eproperties/). In other case do the substitutions yourself.